# APNS error transmitting to device XXXXXXXXXXXXXX with status 400 and reason BadDeviceToken

Tags: react-native, apple-push-notifications, parse-server

I'm trying to set up Push Notifications for RN app using Parse Server as backend. Android works correctly, but iOS tells "APNS error transmitting to device XXXXXXXXXXXXXX with status 400 and reason BadDeviceToken"

Installation class receive device token and all data that I send. Device token is taken from

```
let deviceToken;
PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener('register', token => {
deviceToken = token
});

...

async function setInstallationObject(donorId) {
 let installationController = 
 Parse.CoreManager.getInstallationController();

 installationController
 .currentInstallationId()
 .then(function(iid) {
  let installationObject = Parse.Object.extend('_Installation');
  const installation = new installationObject();
  installation.set('GCMSenderId', 'xxxxxxxx');
  installation.set('installationId', iid);
  installation.set('deviceType', iOS ? 'ios' : 'android');
  installation.set('appName', 'MMB');
  installation.set('appIdentifier', DeviceInfo.getBundleId());
  installation.set('channels', []);
  installation.set('timeZone', 'america/los_angeles');
  installation.set('pushType', iOS ? 'APN' : 'GCM');
  installation.set('appVersion', DeviceInfo.getVersion());
  installation.set('deviceToken', deviceToken);
  installation.set('donorId', donorId);
  installation
    .save()
    .then(() => {})
    .catch(() => {});
 }).catch(() => {});
}
```

Parse is configured with token-based authentication(.p8), the token is working on Firebase(I received a test Push Notification), so I exclude version that the trouble in my key.

Doesn't matter what environment I using, prod or dev, I can't see the notifications on each of them.

**Parse configurations**

```
const express = require('express');
const ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
const ParseDashboard = require('parse-dashboard');
const PushAdapter = require('@parse/push-adapter').default;
const path = require('path');
const scheming = require('./helpers/scheming.js');

require('dotenv').config();

const databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI;

if (!databaseUri) {
  console.log('DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to 
  localhost.');
 }

const pushOptions = {
 ios: {
  token: {
   key: process.env.IOS_key,
   keyId: process.env.IOS_keyId,
   teamId: process.env.IOS_teamId
  },
  topic: process.env.IOS_BundleId,
  production: process.env.IOS_production
 },
 android: {
  apiKey: process.env.Android_APIkey
 }
};

const api = new ParseServer({
 databaseURI: databaseUri, 
 cloud: __dirname+'/cloud/main.js',
 appId: process.env.APP_ID,
 masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY,
 serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL,
 publicServerURL: process.env.SERVER_URL,
 appName: process.env.APP_NAME,
 push: {
  adapter: new PushAdapter(pushOptions)
 }
});

 const dashboardConfig = {
  'allowInsecureHTTP': true,
  'trustProxy': 1,
  'apps': [{
    appId: process.env.APP_ID,
    masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY,
    serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL,
    appName: process.env.APP_NAME
  }],
  'users': [
   {
    'user': process.env.ParseDashboardLogin,
    'pass': process.env.ParseDashboardPass
   }
  ]
 };
```

**Packages on server**

```
"dependencies": {
 "@parse/push-adapter": "^3.2.0",
 "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
 "express": "^4.17.1",
 "mailgun-js": "^0.22.0",
 "moment": "^2.24.0",
 "moment-business-days": "^1.1.3",
 "parse": "^2.8.0",
 "parse-dashboard": "^2.0.5",
 "parse-server": "^3.9.0",
 "twilio": "^3.37.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
 "csv-parser": "^2.3.2"
}
```

Comment: Can you also share your server configuration?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo I updated

Comment: Your setup looks right. Just in case, can you try `const api = new ParseServer({ ... push: pushOptions}); `? Can you also share your package.json?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo I added my package.json

Comment: @DaviMacêdo `const api = new ParseServer({ ... push: pushOptions});` doesn't help. But errors disappear, anyway push notification isn't sent

Comment: What do you have logged in Push Status? Any other log in Parse Server?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo, I get rid of the Parse Push Notifications, I switch to Firebase Cloud Messaging API. Thank you for the replies